# On PDF/Reader gem, how to treat all PDF files in directory

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, pdf

I'v written this script that will permit me to parse PDF File

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pdf/reader'
reader = PDF::Reader.new("file.pdf")
reader.pages.each do |page|
zmer= page.text
puts zmer.scan(/TEXT1[\s\S]*TEST2/)
end
```

Thing is, I want to do the same for all the files on the same directory (the current code works for one single PDF)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is just [Directory globbing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) which can be done like this to find files in the current directory:

```
Dir['*.pdf'].each do |filename|
  puts "Processing #{filename}..."
end
```

So for your specific code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pdf/reader'
Dir['*.pdf'].each do |filename|
  reader = PDF::Reader.new(filename)
  reader.pages.each do |page|
    zmer = page.text
    puts zmer.scan(/TEXT1[\s\S]*TEST2/)
  end
end
```

For more examples, see: http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/a/dir2.htm

Comment: Works like a charm, many thanks for the answer (and for the very useful link) !